# Virtual CD / DVD burner

Tags: virtualization, dvd, cd, burning

I have a file in iTunes on Windows in VirtualBox that can be burned to CD / DVD. I could burn this file to a CD / DVD and rip it to my computer but I don't want to waste a CD / DVD so I'm looking for a way to create a virtual device in Linux Mint / Ubuntu that can be mounted in VirtualBox as CD / DVD burner and write the data from iTunes into an image file. Is something like that possible? How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
I found Phantom Drive for Windows and it does exactly what I need. But it would be great to have such tool for Linux.

Comment: You could mount the optical drive of the host and burn with that!

Comment: My host has no optical drive and I don't want to buy a CD that I would throw away after this

Comment: What do you mean by virtual device, CD/DVD burner?

Comment: I mean a device that looks like a CD/DVD burner for other programs but it's virtual and creates images. So that I can use it in VirtualBox as CD burner.

Comment: In iTunes I only can burn the playlist. I can't create an image or create an iso file. I need a CD burner but currently I don't have one. I want to create a virtual device that can be used as CD burner.

Comment: What of the `dd` command?

Comment: How would I use the `dd` command to create device that looks like a CD burner and can be used as optical device in VirtualBox?

Comment: It create images from file so you don't need a virtual device it's run like this `dd if=/path/to/itunes/files of=/path/to/file.iso`

Comment: From which file? I don't have a file. I have iTunes. It's a program and its only function is to burn to a CD through a CD burner.

Comment: Itunes has a location for the stored music files, not so? I believe you want to burn these music files?

Comment: I have an Audible .aax file. The only way to convert it to mp3 is to burn it to CD through iTunes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDemu - a virtual CD/DVD drive for Linux

Comment: It's CD/DVD drive. I need CD/DVD RW drive